# F# BinaryTernaryTree

Tags: f#, binary-tree

I have to define a BinaryTernay Tree. I have defined this as

```
type Tree<'T> =
| Simple  of 'T
| Complex of  Tree<'T*'T>
| SuperComplex of Tree<'T*'T*'T>
```

With this I am able to form the below trees

```
let example1 = Complex ( SuperComplex ( Simple((1,2),(4,5),(6,7))))
let example2 = SuperComplex( Complex ( Simple ((1,2,3),(3,4,5)) )
```

I wanted to create a tree where  the child tree containing values of the '
tuple type either ('T*'T) or ('T*'T*'T) or a combination of both

I tried the below

```
type Tree<'T> =
  | Leaf of 'T
  | Complex of list<Tree<'T>>
```

But I got the list type constructor allows arbitrary many number of children Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear exactly what kind of tree you want. It looks like you are confusing the *children* of a node (they will have type `Tree<'T>`) with the *data* it contains (which has type `'T`).

From what I understand, this seems to be what you want:

```
type Tree<'T> =
  | Simple of 'T
  | Complex of Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>
  | SuperComplex of Tree<'T> * Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>
```

The leaves of this tree contain one data element, and each internal node has either two or three children.

If you are actually implementing a [2-3 tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree), then your internal nodes will have both children *and* data (either 1 data and 2 children, or 2 data and 3 children), and the leaves have one or two data.

```
type Tree<'T> =
  | InternalTwo of Tree<'T> * 'T * Tree<'T>
  | InternalThree of Tree<'T> * 'T * Tree<'T> * 'T * Tree<'T>
  | LeafOne of 'T
  | LeafTwo of 'T * 'T
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a tree that allows only two or three children, then you can use something like this:

```
type Tree<'T> =
  | Simple  of 'T
  | Binary of Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>
  | Ternary of Tree<'T> * Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>
```

In your original example, you're using `Tree<'T * 'T>` as a child of your `Complex` node - this means different thing than what you might expect. It means that you have just a *single* child tree containing values of the tuple type. So, you can create tree containing just a single sub-tree, but with multiple values in the leaf.

What you need instead is *two* child trees (or *three* child trees in the `SuperComplex` case) containing values of the same type. That's what the above definition uses.

Comment: We need to have a  single child tree containing values of the tuple type. The child tree should be able to hold  Simple ( 1 ,2 ) and Simple ( 4,5,6) at the same time.